# Vscode intelliSense does not work for wx module

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-python

I installed the latest version of vscode, python and wxPython module. 
In vscode, the wx module do not have IntelliSense feature. When I type wx plus'.', nothing pops.

While the object (e.g wx.Frame) do have IntelliSense result.

Since the wx module has the largest number of member, I want to enable it

Simplest code:

```
import wx
# Next, create an application object.
app = wx.App()
# Then a frame.
frm = wx.Frame(None, title="Hello World")
# Show it.
frm.Show()
# Start the event loop.
app.MainLoop()
```